# Download a CSV file with python requests from an authenticated URL

Tags: python, session, python-requests

For one of my project I need to fetch a CSV file from a website authenticated URL. Unfortunately there is no API to do it. So that is why I decided to use requests with sessions to fetch it.

The login page is:
http://extranet.ffbb.com/fbi/identification.do

I checked on the page for the login and password names in the HTML code. Login is "identificationBean.identifiant" and password is "identificationBean.mdp".

So I try to connect and to display the returned HTML with the following code but it returns the HTML code of a wrong login/password (like if I type a wrong login/pass from my browser). And I am sure my credentials are right.

```
login = "my_login"
password = "my_password"

with requests.Session() as session:
    data = {
        'identificationBean.identifiant': '{}'.format(config.login),
        'identificationBean.mdp': '{}'.format(config.password)
    }
    url = 'http://extranet.ffbb.com/fbi/identification.do'
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    print(response.text)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: you have to replicate EVERYTHING the browser is doing. not just what's in the login form, but any cookies the server had set.

Comment: have verified the result of method `.format(config.login)` returns the credentials properly?

Comment: @MarcB: as I see in requests documentation, sessions handle cookies no ? "The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance"

Comment: @tenwest: I check and I am sure my crendential are valid.

Comment: yes, but what about any cookies that are set by the browser initially hittingthe login page?  you're just jumping into a post directly, without simulating what the browser does by actually loading the login page first. that means you won't be sending anti-spoofing tokens, etc...

Comment: Mm. Did not think about this. I can see there is a JSESSIONID set in my cookies. Do you think it can be a clue?

Comment: I added a GET request to the homepage of the website just after initializing my session to fetch every cookie or parameter. But It is not resolving my problem.